# When using findall, TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python

I am trying to implement this class and I am having trouble with the getPostFix method. I don't understand how to fix the error that I am getting.

This is the **str** method in the class just for reference.

```
    # Returns the string representation of the Calc.
    def __str__(self):
        
        theCalc = ""
        theCalc += 'Input is: ' + self.getInput() + '\n'
        theCalc += 'Postfix input is: ' + self.getPostFix() + '\n'
        theCalc += 'Value is: ' + str(self.evaluate()) + '\n'
        
        return theCalc
```

This is where I am getting the error.

```
    def getPostFix(self):

        result = ""

        # stack used to create postfix string
        self.stack = MyStack()

        input_string = self.getInput()
        input_string_split = [x for x in re.split("(\d*\.?\d*)", input_string) if x != '']
        numbers = re.findall('([0-9.]+)', input_string_split, re.DOTALL)

        for i in input_string_split:

            if i in numbers:
                result += i


            elif isOperator(i):
                while True:
                    topItem = self.stack.getTop()
                    if self.stack.size == 0 or topItem == '(':
                        self.stack.push(i)
                        break
                    else:
                        precedence_i = getPrecedence(i)
                        precedence_topItem = getPrecedence(topItem)

                        if precedence_i > precedence_topItem:
                            self.stack.push(i)
                            break
                        else:
                            ipop = self.stack.pop()
                            result += ipop if ipop else ""
                            #result += self.stack.pop()

            elif i == '(':
                self.stack.push(i)

            elif i == ')':
                ipop = self.stack.pop()

                while ipop != '(':
                    result += ipop if ipop else ""
                    ipop = self.stack.pop()

            elif i == '=':
                ipop = self.stack.pop()
                result += ipop if ipop else ""
                #result += self.stack.pop()

        while not self.stack.size == 0:
            ipop = self.stack.pop()
            result += ipop if ipop else ""

        return result
```

And here is the error. It says it's expecting a string, but isn't input_string_split a list of strings? I don't understand how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx", line 9, in <module>
    print(calc)
  File "xxx", line 23, in __str__
    theCalc += 'Postfix input is: ' + self.getPostFix() + '\n'
  File "xxx", line 50, in getPostFix
    numbers = re.findall('([0-9.]+)', input_string_split, re.DOTALL)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I am updating to show my attempt at using @Xinthral's answer below. I added a helper function:

```
def isOperand(c):
    number = re.search('([0-9.]+)', c)
    if number != None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

so now the if statement in the for loop is:

```
if isOperand(i):
  result += (i + ' ')
```

But I get the output below which indicates to me that the rest of the for loop is not being executed. That is, it is not iterating through the list and finding operators or parentheses etc.

```
Input is: 3.2+.4*5.67/6.145=
Postfix input is: 3.2 .4 5.67 6.145 
Value is: None

Input is: 11.897/3.4+9.2-0.4*6.9/12.6-16.7=
Postfix input is: 11.897 3.4 9.2 0.4 6.9 12.6 16.7 
Value is: None

Input is: 234+34*65=
Postfix input is: 234 34 65 
Value is: None
```

Comment: Input string is being passed to the regex as a list, maybe try:
`numbers = re.findall('([0-9.]+)', ' '.join(input_string_split), re.DOTALL)`
or moving the numbers check to be an individual variable inside the loop and check it line by line?

Comment: You already know the root cause. Now how to fix it depends on the output you want.
A simple `''.join(input_string_split)` will convert list of string to string.

Comment: @Xinthral thanks. can you show me how to do the second part? moving the check into the loop?

Comment: It looks like the only part that's not running is the self.evaluate() method. Is this a wrapper for python's eval() method?

Comment: @Xinthral Actually I know that method isn't working because I haven't written it yet. When I say its not working, what I mean is that in the getPostFix method only the "if isOperand" method seems to be working, it doesn't go any further. So, it's not capturing operators ("+-/*), parentheses, etc. I think it has something to do with the isOperand helper function but I am not sure.

Comment: @Xinthral I outlined this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256337/why-is-only-the-first-if-statement-executing-in-my-getpostfix-method. You'll see I use different code for isOperand, but that was to make everything else hang together. Let me know if you have any insights!

Answer (score 1):

The following should help, I think the logic is just out of order. Your `for` loop is already going over the whole 'input_string_split', so check each line would be checked during the loop.  Hopefully this helps, let me know.

Before:

```
input_string_split = [x for x in re.split("(\d*\.?\d*)", input_string) if x != '']
numbers = re.findall('([0-9.]+)', input_string_split, re.DOTALL)

for i in input_string_split:
  if i in numbers:
    result += i
```

After:

```
input_string_split = [x for x in re.split("(\d*\.?\d*)", input_string) if x != '']
numbers = list()

for i in input_string_split:
  number = re.search('([0-9.]+)', i)
  if number != None: 
    numbers.append(i)
    result += i
```

Comment: I didn't account for any of the following code here, so adjusting the pop/push's or exception handling may be necessary.

Comment: I updated my question to show how I tried to implement your approach. It is executing the first if statement, but it's not executing the rest for some reason that I cannot figure out!